# Is it okay to segue, without calling a completion handler, if not needed?

Tags: ios, swift

Say I have a function that has a completion handler, then calls another function, with a completion handler like this:

```
func register(withCompletion complete: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
    self.sendRegisterRequest(withCompletion: { (error: Error?) -> () in

        if error != nil {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ErrorVCSegue", sender: nil)
        }
        else {
            complete()
        }
    })
}
```

In the event of an error, it will segue away with calling `complete()`.

Am I ok to segue away like this, without calling `complete()`? I do not need to return from this function as I'm now wanting to go to another View Controller.

Thanks.

Comment: This is the one way of doing, better you send the error status in closure while calling, there you can check the status of error and do appropriate actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad idea. A completion handler should be called no matter what. The caller is waiting for a response. It wants to know when it is done. That's the whole point of having a completion handler.

In your case (like many other cases), it would be much better if the completion handler accepted a boolean parameter (and/or an error parameter). This way the completion handler provides some basic information about the success or failure of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    register { (error) in
        if error == nil {
            // do what you want in success case
        } else {
             self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ErrorVCSegue", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}

func register(withCompletion complete: @escaping ((_ error: Error?) -> Void)) {
    self.sendRegisterRequest(withCompletion: { (error: Error?) -> () in
        complete(Error)
    })
}
```

Thanks:)